# redis, jedis, kubernetes, connection refused

Tags: java, kubernetes, redis, connection

I have trouble understanding what the problem is. My application in Spring Boot 2 tries to connect to Redis but the connection is rejected. The application runs in Kubernetes as Pod. I don't understand why after entering the container where my application process is running, I try to connect to Redis using redis-cli and it works.

See here:

```
/opt/transformer # redis-cli -h redis-master-service.default.svc.cluster.local -p 6379 ping
PONG
```

But my application still throws exception while connect to Redis.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:292) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:511) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.fetchConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:193) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:144) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:105) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:209) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:189) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:176) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.contains(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:281) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.lambda$insert$0(KeyValueTemplate.java:176) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:362) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.insert(KeyValueTemplate.java:174) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueTemplate.insert(RedisKeyValueTemplate.java:158) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.insert(KeyValueTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.support.SimpleKeyValueRepository.save(SimpleKeyValueRepository.java:77) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at io.meksula.transformer.config.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:29) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:84) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:370) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:15) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:283) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed to create socket.
    at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:110) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:226) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:135) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:309) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.initializeFromClientConfig(BinaryJedis.java:87) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.<init>(BinaryJedis.java:292) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.<init>(Jedis.java:167) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:177) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:918) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar!/:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:431) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar!/:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:356) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar!/:2.9.0]
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:75) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:80) ~[jedis-3.6.2.jar!/:na]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

My application works fine on my local machine with local Redis container.

I can't understand why nmap returns that host is down:

```
/opt/transformer # nmap redis-master-service.default.svc.cluster.local
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-08-20 13:39 UTC
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.06 seconds
```

After all, redis-cli connected correctly. Why is this happening?

[edit]

Redis Pod definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  containers:
  - name: redis
    image: redis:5.0.4
    command:
      - redis-server
      - "/redis-master/redis.conf"
    env:
    - name: MASTER
      value: "true"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 6379
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "0.1"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /redis-master-data
      name: data
    - mountPath: /redis-master
      name: config
  volumes:
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: redis-config
        items:
        - key: redis-config
          path: redis.conf
```

Redis Service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-master-service
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
```

Spring Boot application.yaml:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: ${MESSAGE_BROKER_HOST}
  redis:
    host: ${CACHE_HOST}
    port: 6379
```

Environment variables resolved correctly in Spring app, I checked this.

I tried to connect to Service using telnet and this work well too.

```
/opt/transformer # telnet redis-master-service.default.svc.cluster.local 6379
Connected to redis-master-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Could you provide the spring boot properties file where the redis connection are specified? Also the kubernetes configuration would be interesting, are you using a service/replica set/pod ? port configuration is relevant.

Comment: @usuario thanks for response. I just edited my post and added some configuration files. I'm stuck :(

Comment: IMHO I believe the environmental variables are the key here, since I am not able to find something wrong. what does `${CACHE_HOST}` in your application.yml resolves to? Is the Spring Boot app running inside the kubernetes cluster or outside? From where are you executing `redis-cli` and `nmap`?

Comment: `redis-cli` and `nmap` I run from container where Java process is running. ${CACHE_HOST} is variable from ConfigMap and resolves correctly to redis-master-service.default.svc.cluster.local

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where problem was, but I resolve it by replacing `jedis` with `lettuce` redis connection library.

```
//        <dependency>
//            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
//            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
//            <version>3.6.2</version>
//        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```